# Meaning of せっかく

Tags: set-phrases

> せっかくだから、色違いでもう一つ買おうかな

What is the meaning of `せっかくだから` here?
I had the understanding that せっかく/わざわざ are used to express the notion of someone undergoing lot of effort/pain to do something for us.

Comment: What happened before this line?

Answer (score 1):

せっかく insinuates that some type of work or hardship has been endured (by someone) or there is some type of importance happening.  What happened before the line could have relevance, but the beauty of it is that infers a lot even without. (Perhaps they came a long way to the store. Or maybe they are just in need of sweaters [or whatever the article in question is]).  I always think of わざわざ as going out of ones way, and not really the same as せっかく。  You'll also never hear わざわざだから but せっかくだから is very common.